# How to make 2 layout in one view at gridview android studio

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I will make menu using grid view under another layout.
I have made gridview using recyclerview but cannot show top layout
my code is

activity_grid_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.HomeActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dataList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

grid_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20sp"
                android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/news"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the result

[image: the result 2]

please help me to resolve this, because I'm the beginner for android developer
Thanks

Comment: Your expected image and output is same . Please post the expect result for better understanding

Comment: sorry, I post the wrong picture. I have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include your `LinearLayout` inside  `grid_layout.xml` instead add this inside `activity_grid_layout.xml` just above recyclerView

After doing above changes your layout as follow:

***activity_grid_layout.xml***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".main.HomeActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutImg"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/sunflower_black"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dataList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutImg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***grid_layout.xml:***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="20sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/news"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it's work.. thank u so much for helping me.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Happy coding..!